# Unable to import tensorflow-gpu in PyCharm using Conda environment but able to import it from CMD after activating the same environment

Tags: tensorflow, pycharm, conda

I am attempting to use tensorflow-gpu on my own machine running Windows 10. My environment is as follows:

```
GPU - NVIDIA GeForce MX150 2Gb memory
OS - Windows 10
CUDA version - 10.0
CUDNN - 7.4.2
Anaconda - 3
PyCharm Professional 2019.1.2
```

If I open my terminal in windows (cmd) and then write "conda activate my_env" after which I run the python interpreter via  the "python" command and I import tensorflow I do not get any errors. I also check if it is compiled for CUDA and if it can find my GPU and everything works.

However, in PyCharm I am unable to import tensorflow. I get error "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.". I was getting this error while trying to set-up the right cuda version with the right cudnn and the right tensorflow-gpu version. However, like I said I can import it through my terminal (after activating the environment) but it is unable to import in PyCharm.

I have been looking online but couldn't find anything similar to my problem. Has anyone else had this issue before?

Also, I am sure that PyCharm is setup using the right environment interpreter from conda. I also tried to activate the conda environment through the PyCharm terminal and then import tensorflow but I got the same error there so I think it could be a PyCharm issue.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, so it was something simple. I just had to restart my computer. Then PyCharm could import tensorflow.